# Get exception when just started py script, but all work

Tags: python, exception, rss, feedparser

Interesting situation!

I has parser.py script, link to it below in [1](https://github.com/gudsaf/newsbot/tree/dev), with feedparser library. 
When i just started it, i get such exceptions:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 172.3757.67)
pydev debugger: process 20017 is connecting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 354, in evaluate_expression
    compiled = compile(expression, '<string>', 'eval')
  File "<string>", line 1
    feedparser.parse(http://www.malware-traffic-analysis.net/blog-entries.rss)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 1134, in do_it
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluate_expression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 356, in evaluate_expression
    Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<string>", line 1
    feedparser.parse(http://www.malware-traffic-analysis.net/blog-entries.rss)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even more, i didn't go to point with:

> feedparser.parse(http://www.malware-traffic-analysis.net/blog-entries.rss)

Such problem appear over first import in script which import json!
Also in my code i get http strings from txt file, like:
    RssProcess('rsslinks.txt')
So, first i thing that problem in this file and delete string

> http[:]//www.malware-traffic-analysis.net/blog-entries.rss

from it. But it didn't help! So i has script that works perfectly, but it get exceptions which doesn't stop it. Exceptions i saw in PyCharm debugger.

---

My specs:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- pycharm 2017.2
- python 3.6.2

---

[Link to GitHub](https://github.com/gudsaf/newsbot/tree/dev)

Comment: can you include the actual relevant code snippet

Comment: here we are, in Git